# Swift: extending initializer with `required init` to `Decodable`

Tags: swift, mocking, decoding

In Swift, I have a class `DemoClass` that implements `DemoClassProtocol`

Because I need to call .init on other `DemoClassPrototocol` classes, I've implemented:

```
class DemoClass: DemoClassProtocol {
    required init() { }
}

protocol DemoClassProtocol {
    init()
}
```

In my test target, I want to extend `DemoClass` with:

```
extension DemoClass: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // decoding logic here
    }
}
```

so I can more easily test encoded objects.

BUT: if I implement the decoder initializer above, Swift insists:

> Initializer requirement 'init(from:)' can only be satisfied by a 'required' initializer in the definition of non-final class 'SessionBatch'

Given I only want to implement `decodable` in the test suite, I don't want a required init(from decoder: Decoder) in the class in the non-test target.

It seems extending with Decodable is a common test strategy, so I'm assuming there's a straightforward way around this, but I'm struggling to think (or google) anything useful. Any thoughts on how to extend a class with a `required init` to include Decodable's initializer?

Comment: So if Decodable isn’t suitable here why not just create and configure your test objects in code? You can do it as static properties in an extension or have a specific factory type if want to move it away from the test code and make it more reusable

Comment: Use a struct instead